# Object assign extend immutable array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutable.js

I want to have a immutable original array of object and extend a new one, but seems the code below did nto produce the right result. obj3 became an object instead of an array of object. I even tried lodash's extend.

```
var obj1 = [{
  abc: 'abc value'
}, {
  def: 'def value'
}];

var obj2 = {
  def: 'new def value'
};

/*var obj3 = _.extend({}, obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj3)
*/

var obj3 = Object.assign({},obj1,obj2);
```

https://jsbin.com/bawadeqicu/edit?html,js,output

My desire output is

```
obj1: [{"abc":"abc value"},{"def":"def value"}] // immutable
obj3: [{"abc":"abc value"},{"def":"new def value"}]
```

Comment: Clone the array and assign `obj2` as the second element of the new copy. There is no "pretty" way to do this. `var obj3 = obj1.slice(); obj3[1] = obj2;`. I mean, you could do `var obj3 = Object.assign([], obj1, {1: obj2});` but that seems more magic ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: check this link https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable/issues/43

Comment: Why is the second object updated? Because it has a property `def`? Do you want to match/merge objects based on property? What should happen if the property name was different? would `obj2` simply be added to the array? Would the objects be merged in a different? What if both objects in the array had the same property? What if they have other properties as well? You haven't actually described what the merge rules are so any answer you get will just be an interpretation based on the specific input and output you provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.entries()`, `.map()` spread element at `obj1` parameter passed to `Object.assign()` to spread the object elements of `obj1` array to the new array.

```js
var obj1 = [{
  abc: 'abc value'
}, {
  def: 'def value'
}];

var obj2 = {
  def: 'new def value'
};

var obj3 = Object.entries(Object.assign({},...obj1, obj2))
           .map(([prop, value]) => ({[prop]:value}));

console.log(
  `obj1:${JSON.stringify(obj1)}`
  , `\nobj2:${JSON.stringify(obj2)}`
  , `\nobj3:${JSON.stringify(obj3)}`
)
```

Comment: this is possibly the correct answer, you need to split the keys into distinct objects,

Comment: This will fail if the objects have the same property name.

Comment: @FelixKling  Can you describe what you mean?

Comment: If all objects had the property `abc`, not `def`, then your code would result in an array with a single object. Of course that might be the expected result, I don't know.

Comment: @FelixKling Still not following. Which portion of `javascript` needs to be improved?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/809Lbxh6/ . Note how there is only a single object in the last array. Maybe nothing has to be improved. I'm just saying that this is something to be aware of. I shouldn't have said "this will fail". The OP didn't provide any explanation of the merge rules/logic, so everything is pretty much speculation IMO.

Comment: @FelixKling That is an interesting case. First inquiry for such an example would be what is purpose? That is, if you reviewed a Question having same contents, given `Object.assign()` is within Question body, what are the possible expected results? How would you view the case, even with explanation? Perhaps at least three different outcomes; push, match, exclude? Though at present Question both inputs and expected result appear to be clear? Unless and until OP edits Question providing further clarification, is it necessary to consider all possible inputs and potential expected outputs?

Comment: @FelixKling Also, have no issue, here, referring OP to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if an edit to described requirement at original Question is on its face substantially different from plain text of original requirement.

Comment: confusion, i think i rather don't do inmmutable here, just use push() to a new var.

Comment: @ElkenChen _"confusion, i think i rather don't do inmmutable here, just use push() to a new var."_ Not certain what you mean? Does `javascript` at Answer not return expected result described at original Question _"My desire output is

`obj1: [{"abc":"abc value"},{"def":"def value"}] // immutable
obj3: [{"abc":"abc value"},{"def":"new def value"}]`"_?

Answer (score 2):

Going immutable

Instead of passing the object and mutating it, we will be better off creating a completely new object:

```
const person = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 28
}
const newPerson = Object.assign({}, person, {
  age: 30
})
console.log(newPerson === person) // false
console.log(person) // { name: 'John', age: 28 }
console.log(newPerson) // { name: 'John', age: 30 }
```

[source](http://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/)

Comment: You should elaborate on this; link-only answers are frowned on here since the link may not survive the passage of time.

Comment: @Jacob you mean i should write the answer and refer to the link too ??

Comment: I want array of object,not just object.